# Connecting laravel app to another database - Laravel 5.8

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, database-connection

I am trying to connect on another `mysql database` on a local server running on the same `network`. But when running `php artisan migrate` it just freezes and nothing happens, the `logs` is also empty. How can I achieve this?

**Here's my .env file**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:uzO/+1oxld1Bt9mudIHqb8lz3v8w2qOdmAc3IavWALY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST= 192.xxx.x.xxx
DB_PORT= xxxxx  //sample port
DB_DATABASE=testlaravel 
DB_USERNAME=xxxxxx // sample username
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx // sample password
```

Comment: Are you able to successfully connect to the database via `mysql` command line? The issue may be unrelated to to Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

db_host should be "127.0.0.1" please try this.